# Present ViewController from UNNotificationRequest when user taps on notification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications, local

I am currently developing an app in Swift 4 that includes local notifications. I am trying to run a specific piece of code when the user taps on the notification like presenting a specific ViewController. I can't find the answer on stack overflow because most of the functions in App delegate are deprecated.

Here is the code I use for the notifications:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Consejo"
content.body = "Haga clic en la notificacion para ver el consejo del dia."

content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

var dateComponents = DateComponents()

    if let hour = pickerdatehour {
        if let minute = pickerdateminute{

dateComponents.hour = hour
dateComponents.minute = minute
dateComponents.second = 0

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

The code I am trying to execute from the app delegate is:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()





    return true

}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("tes")
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let otherVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "consejos") as! ConsejosViewController
    window?.rootViewController = otherVC;
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("tes")

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let otherVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "consejos") as! ConsejosViewController
        window?.rootViewController = otherVC;
}




}
```

What am I doing wrong? The code on app delegate is never even executed.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `UNUserNotificationCenter` delegate to self to call `UNUserNotificationCenter`'s delegate methods like below:

```
 let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
 center.delegate = self
```

Comment: nope, still not calling it. I added the delegate to self in the view controller and it still didn't execute the code. The notifications are being sent successfully but there is no code executed when I click them. I think adding delegate to self didn't work because the code I need to execute is in the app delegate not in the view controller.

Comment: Then you should also implement `UNUserNotificationCenter` delegate methods in App Delegate.

Comment: already did: @UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

Comment: set `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`